# How to make Mathematica show parentheses using the AntykwaTorunska font correctly?

Tags: latex, fonts, style

I am currently on a Windows 10 machine using Mathematica 11.0.1.0 and on which I installed [the AntykwaTorunska fonts](http://jmn.pl/en/antykwa-torunska/) (light, bold, condensed, etc).

Here you can see a part of the screenshot of the Fonts screen from Windows, displaying the most common characters in the Font's style (AntykwaTorunskaLight-Regular). **Note how the opening (closing) parenthesis has a thicker end on the top (bottom).**

[image: AntykwaTorunskaLight-Regular font Windows]

With TeXstudio I can successfully use this font as well by using

> ```
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
>
> \usepackage[light,math]{anttor}
>
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> ```

[image: Output from LaTeX]

Using Mathematica I can show text and parentheses (normal and in bold for completeness) like so:

> ```
> Style["The quick brown fox jump ()\!\(\*StyleBox[\"(\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\")\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)", FontFamily ->"AntykwaTorunska Light", 40]
> ```

resulting in output:

[image: AntykwaTorunskaLight-Regular font Mathematica]

**Conclusion:** All the normal text is put out correctly in the ANTTOR font but parentheses seem to misbehave. Is there any way I can get Mathematica to display the parentheses in Mathematica such that they look identical to the ones put out by Windows or LateX?

Comment: Due to lack of reputation I could not give the source (http://jmn.pl/en/antykwa-torunska/) from where I installed the font, nor the output generated by LaTeX (https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6N6o.png) in the original question.

Comment: [Can you try if this solution works for you?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133163/12) (I cannot try now)  If you only want to use this font for labelling figures that you will later export (perhaps for use in a LaTeX document), consider using my [MaTeX package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html).

Comment: Very nice Szabolcs! It does work for parenthesis, but, although not specifically asked in this thread, I also notice that characters like \rho and \beta are not in the correct fonts. Since these are most likely not considered operators it seems

"   PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> True} "

does not work for those symbols in Mathematica.

Comment: To add to this; I also installed MaTeX and tried to change the font to ANTTOR which worked untill I wanted it to output \rho and it gave an error. It seems Mathematica(?) has some issues using Greek symbols or something..? Pretty sure the symbols I want (normal greek ones) are in the font as I can look them up in Windows as well as output them using LaTeX.

Comment: MaTeX troubles are a different issue entirely, and it would be better to discuss them elsewhere ([do you have enough reputation for chat?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53995/matex)).  But this works fine: `MaTeX[{\[Rho], "\\rho"}, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage[light,math]{anttor}"}]`.

Comment: But MaTeX is really designed for short labels to be used in figures, particularly for formulas.  If you want to have a paragraph of text in this font, then MaTeX is not the appropriate solution.

Comment: Ideally I would be able to display a \rho without MaTeX but it does offer a good enough solution if I can't do so without. If there is no clearcut answer like there was with the parentheses (in terms of Mathematica options like OperatorSubstitution ) then I think this question can be considered answered :).

Comment: I suspect that there is a similar option that controls the substitution of other characters, but I can't spend the time to go digging for it now. Finding this other one took a considerable amount of time.  "font substitution" may be a good starting keyword. Perhaps someone else will figure it out.